# Given two adjacent sides of a rectangle are equivalent, prove that the quadrilateral is a square.

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, euclidean-geometry

In Geometry class today, we were talking about quadrilaterals and the types of them. I was wondering that if, given a rectangle with two adjacent equal congruent sides, if that was enough to prove it was a square. I thought *surely, it MUST be a square, because of...* And there I was lost for a while. I flipped through my notes looking for some theorem that proved this in a step or two, and, finding none, I tried my own way of proving it. Did I prove it correctly? If not, how do I correct it? Finally, is there a shorter, more elegant way to execute it? (*The below is the proof I have.*)

---

```
A               B
 ┌─┬────┼────┬─┐
 ├─┘         └─┤
 │             │
 │             ┼
 │             │
 ├─┐         ┌─┤
 └─┴─────────┴─┘
D               C
```

**Conjecture:** If $\overline{AB}\cong\overline{BC}$ and $ABCD$ is a rectangle, then $ABCD$ is a square.

*Proof.*

$$\begin{array}{cc|cc}
\text{Statements}&&\text{Reasons}\\\hline
\overline{DB}\cong\overline{DB}&&\text{Reflexive property of Congruency}\\\hline
\angle ABD\cong\angle BDC&&\text{AIA* Theorem}\\
\angle DBC\cong\angle ADB\\\hline
\triangle ABD\cong \triangle CBD&&\text{SAS** Theorem}\\\hline
\overline{AD}\cong\overline{CB}&&\text{CPCTC***}\\
\overline{AB}\cong\overline{CD}\\\hline
ABCD\text{ is a square}&&\text{Definition of Square}&\blacksquare
\end{array}$$

---

<sub>*Alternate Interior Angle</sub>

<sub>**Side angle side</sub>

<sub>***Congruent Parts of a Triangle are Congruent</sub>

Comment: The opposite sides of a rectangle are always congruent. If two adjacent sides are congruent, then their opposite sides are also congruent to each other and to them. Therefore all 4 sides are congruent, therefore square. QED

Comment: Oh, hm, I forgot about the definition of rectangle >_>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given: ABCD is a rectangle, AB = BC

Prove: ABCD is a square

Step 1: AB = CD, BC = AD (property of rectangle: opposite sides are congruent)

Step 2: AB = AD, BC = CD (transitive property from Step 1 and Given)

Step 3: ABCD is a square (definition of square: rectangle where all sides are congruent)

QED

Comment: I wouldn't say that Step 1 follows from the *definition of rectangle* ... at least not the definition I use. A rectangle is, simply, a quadrilateral with four right angles (hence the name); thus, it happens to be a *parallelogram* (each pair of opposite sides are parallel, because they make a supplementary pair of adjacent interior angles). Now, the opposite-sides-are-congruent thing is a *property* of parallelograms (which is proven more-or-less the way OP did it, but in a bit more generality), which makes it a *property* of rectangles, but it's not part of the *definition*.

Comment: @Blue Good point; I edited it to say "property" rather than "definition".